# JCL SORT Decimal to Non decimal

Tags: mainframe, dfsort, syncsort

I want to convert a decimal value for e.g. 12.34 in input file to 1234  in output file. The field is defined as s9(11)v9(02) comp-3

Comment: Although I personally don't mind helping people with their homework... You have to provide some of the code you have tried thus far.

Comment: I tried findrep in sort option. OUTREC FINDREP=((IN=C’.’), (OUT=C’’))

Comment: Are you able to show me the full job? I assume you're using JCL, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
outrec fields=(1,13,pd,to=zd,length=25)
```